# Foreach with nested dictionary in xslt

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, dictionary, foreach

I have a dictionary with the following values:

```
<root
    user_salutation="Geachte heer"
    wg="7"
    wgList-0="68"
    wgListCount-0="3"
    wgList-1="65"
    wgListCount-1="1"
    wgList-2="62" 
    wgListCount-2="1"
    wgList-3="58"
    wgListCount-3="2"
/>
```

How do i link the list and count together in a foreach?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration ="yes" encoding="ISO-8859 1"/>

 <xsl:variable name="style">
  body {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 11px;
  }
  td {
  height: 15px;
  border: 0px;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 11px;
  }
  th {
  background-color: #999999;
  color: white;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 11px;
  }
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="prijs_zichtbaar"> 1 </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:key name="params" match="tag[@name!='param']" use="generate-id(preceding-    sibling::tag[@name='param'][1])" />

  <xsl:template match="tag[@name='param']">
  <xsl:text>param&#10;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('params', generate-id())" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag">
 <xsl:value-of select="concat(' - ', @name, '&#10;')" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>wgp</title>
    <style>
      <xsl:value-of select="$style"/>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
        <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="" >
            <colgroup>
                <col width="200"/>
                <col width="100"/>
                <col width="100"/>
                <col width="100"/>
            </colgroup>

            <tr>
                <th align="left">Soort</th>
                <th align="right">Dag</th>
                <th align="right">Aantal</th>
                <th align="right">Ontvangers</th>
            </tr>

            <xsl:for-each select="root/@*[starts-with(name(),'wgList-')]">
               <xsl:element name="TR">
                 <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 0">
                    <xsl:attribute name="bgcolor">#CCCCCC</xsl:attribute>
                 </xsl:if>

                 <td align="left">wg</td>
                 <td align="right"><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                 <td align="right"><xsl:value-of select="@*[name() = concat('wgListCount-', substring-after(name(current()), '-'))]" /></td>
               </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>

            <xsl:if test="root/@list1 > 0">
                <xsl:element name="TR">
                    <td align="left"><b>subtotaal:</b></td>
                    td align="left"></td>
                    <td align="right">----------------<br/><xsl:value-of select="root/@wg" /></td>
                    <td align="right">----------------<br/><xsl:value-of-select="root/@wg" /></td>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:if>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You will need to explain in more detail what a dictionary has to do with XSLT. Usually XSLT works on XML documents. Thus consider to show the XML input sample you want to process with XSLT and the output you want to create.

Comment: I am trying to send a mail with a overview of information from the dictionary.

Comment: Can you edit your question show a proper sample of the XML you are using? And also, could you show the full XSLT? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am making a guess here, but from looking at your XSLT snippet, it suggests your keys and values are attributes on the **root** element, like so

```
<root
   wgList-0="68"
   wgListCount-0="3"
   wgList-1="65"
   wgListCount-1="4"
   wgList-2="62"
   wgListCount-2="8">
</root>
```

In this case, the XSLT you need to get the key value is this

```
<xsl:value-of 
   select="../@*
     [name() = concat('wgListCount-', substring-after(name(current()), '-'))]"/>
```

What this is doing is getting the part of name of the current attribute that occurs after the hyphen (i.e. either 0, 1 or 2) and then using this value to get the name of the expected **wgListCount** element. This assumes you are currently positioned on the **wgList-** element.

Here is some sample XSLT (I've removed some code just to keep it short and focus on the issue in hand)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="ISO-8859 1"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
         <head>
            <title>wgp</title>
         </head>
         <body>
            <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="">
               <tr>
                  <th align="left">Soort</th>
                  <th align="right">Dag</th>
                  <th align="right">Aantal</th>
                  <th align="right">Ontvangers</th>
               </tr>
               <xsl:for-each select="root/@*[starts-with(name(),'wgList-')]">
                  <xsl:element name="TR">
                     <td align="left">wg</td>
                     <td align="right">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                     </td>
                     <td align="right">
                        <xsl:value-of select="../@*[name() = concat('wgListCount-', substring-after(name(current()), '-'))]"/>
                     </td>
                  </xsl:element>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the above XML, the following is output

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <title>wgp</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="">
         <tr>
            <th align="left">Soort</th>
            <th align="right">Dag</th>
            <th align="right">Aantal</th>
            <th align="right">Ontvangers</th>
         </tr>
         <TR>
            <td align="left">wg</td>
            <td align="right">68</td>
            <td align="right">3</td>
         </TR>
         <TR>
            <td align="left">wg</td>
            <td align="right">65</td>
            <td align="right">1</td>
         </TR>
         <TR>
            <td align="left">wg</td>
            <td align="right">62</td>
            <td align="right">1</td>
         </TR>
         <TR>
            <td align="left">wg</td>
            <td align="right">58</td>
            <td align="right">2</td>
         </TR>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The output is still empty.. i dont know what i am doing wrong

Comment: Can you show a proper sample of the XML you are using? And also, could you edit the question to show the full XSLT? Thanks!

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
  <root user_salutation="Geachte heer" 
  wg="7" 
  wgList-0="68" 
  wgListCount-0="3" 
  wgList-1="65" 
  wgListCount-1="1"
  wgList-2="62" 
  wgListCount-2="1"
  wgList-3="58" 
  wgListCount-3="2"
 />

Comment: @Tsujmi I've noticed the mistake in my answer, which I have now corrected, so hopefully this work for you.